How to Reinitialize Singleton Pages and ViewModels on User Logout and Login in a MAUI Shell App?
Problem Description
I am developing a MAUI app that utilizes Shell tabs alongside a login flow. Each tab’s page and corresponding ViewModel are registered as singletons. Upon the initial load, the pages use the OnAppearing method to call an initialization method from the ViewModel, which fetches data from a local database (using LiteDb) and loads it into an observable collection for the user to view.
Issue Encountered
The application allows the current user to log out, with the following flow:
try
{
    SecureStorage.Default.RemoveAll(); // Clears the session of the logged-in user
    await _repositories.ClearAsync(); // Clears all data created by the current user

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SignInUpPage)}");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Toast.Show("Something went wrong");
}

After navigating back to the SignInUpPage and logging in again, the data from the previous session is still visible on the main tab pages. This is due to the pages and ViewModels being registered as singletons.
Question
What is the best approach to ensure that these pages and ViewModels are destroyed or reinitialized upon a new login? The goal is to have fresh instances that reload data appropriately when a user logs in after logging out.
Page setup
In the MainShellPage.xaml I have the following:
<ShellContent
        Title="Loading"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LoadingPage}"
        Route="LoadingPage" />

    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate account:SignInUpPage}" Route="SignInUpPage" />

    <TabBar Route="MainShellPage">
        <Tab Title="{Binding Dashboard.Title}" Icon="{Binding Dashboard.Icon}">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dashboard:DashboardMainPage}" />
        </Tab> Another tabs .. </TabBar>

When LoadingPage starts in its own viewmodel it decides if the user is authenticated or not.
If user is authenticated it goes to:
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainShellPage)}")

Otherwise
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SignInUpage)}")

The reason of the Loading page:

decide user is authenticated
if default data init was not done yet it fetches data from web api and save into local db
if user was working on something and the app was closed here it checks if there is cached data and load to the app to continue on


Is SignupPage the root of your navigation stack?

No, in the app.xaml.cs i set MainPage = new MainShellPage();

I updated the original post with the Shell Structure.

Can you create a variable somewhere in your navigation stack and see what the first page is in the navigation stack? Shell.Current.Navigation

The first page is the LoadingPage and there is one null item in the navigation stack list in Shell.Current.Navigation.
When I log out in SignInUpPage also the same.

Interesting there seems to be an issue with the way you are maintaining your navigation if this is the case

Navigation stack shouldnt be added only if i use await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("page")? When i use the // shouldnt be added and clears everything?

Why are your Pages and ViewModels registered as singletons? Even if they're used in tabs, they could be transients, because tabs don't create new instances when navigated to. If you change that, you could then assign a new instance of MainShellPage to Application.MainPage after logging in. That should yield the expected results.

Thank you! This solved my problem. I switched to transient and added the line:
App.Current.MainPage = new MainShellPage();
right after clearing the local database and before navigating to the signup page from the logout page. Now, when navigating between tabs after login, the page reinitializes, so all data is reloaded.

I swiched the all tabs pages and viewmodels to transients, and when logout happnes I do the following to reinit MainPage.
try
{
    SecureStorage.Default.RemoveAll(); // Clears the session of the logged-in user
    await _repositories.ClearAsync(); // Clears all data created by the current user 
    App.Current.MainPage = new MainShellPage(); // Reinit main page -> when login again all pages and vms will be reinit
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SignInUpPage)}");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Toast.Show("Something went wrong");
}


You could each ViewModel let implement a specific Interface like IInitialiazble with a property indicating if initialization should be performed.
If a user logs out you could ask your DI to give you all ViewModels implementing the Interface and set the property to true or false. Depending on which value you initialize. After initialization on a ViewModel you change the value of the property so the initalization is only performed once for a usersession.
Example:
    public interface IInitializable
    {
        public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    }

    public ViewModel1:IInitializable{
    public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    
    public void Initialize(){
    if(IsInitialized){
    return;
    }
    // perform Initialization
    }



public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp App { get; set; }
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ViewModel1>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IInitializable>(x => x.GetService<ViewModel1>()); 
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ViewModel2>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IInitializable>(x => x.GetService<ViewModel2>());

        return App =  builder.Build();
    }

    public static void Refresh()
    {
        var viewModels = App.Services.GetServices<IInitializable>();
        foreach (var viewModel in viewModels)
        {
            viewModel.IsInitialized = false;
        }
    }
}

With this Service registration you can get all ViewModels with the marker Interface and still can get each individual by constructor Injection.
/ or calling
public class LoginViewModel{

public void Login(){
MauiProgram.Refresh();
// Perform Login
}
}


You could improve your answer by providing an actual example.

Although I like your solution, but I used Julian's suggestion.
